# The value of the base pointers pointing to object of derived class

Tags: c++

Which of the statements in following piece of code is correct and why?

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    virtual ~ ClassA(){};
    virtual void FunctionA(){};
};

class ClassB
{
public:
    virtual void FunctionB(){};
};

class ClassC : public ClassA,public ClassB
{
public:
};


int main(){ 
    ClassC aObject;
    ClassA* pA=&aObject;
    ClassB* pB=&aObject;
    ClassC* pC=&aObject;
    return 0;
}
```

1. The values of `pA`, `pB` and `pC` are the same;
2. `pC = pA + pB;`
3. `pA` is different from pB;
4. Neither `pA` nor `pB` is equal to `pC`;

Can anybody explain the true story under the phenomenon that base class pointers pointing to derived objects? Not simply store the starting address of the object of derived class?

Comment: I just went over Effective C++, it said in Item 27 that 'Here we're just creating a base class pointer to a derived class object, but sometimes, the two pointer values will not be the same. When that's the case, an offset is applied at runtime to the Derived* pointer to get the correct Base* pointer value.'

Comment: 3 is always true. 2 and 4 could also be true, depending on your compiler. There's no single answer.

Answer (score 0):

pA points to an object of type ClassA. pB points to an object of type ClassB. pC points to an object of type ClassC. Their declarations say so.

An object of type ClassC contains an object of type ClassA and an object of type ClassB. ClassA and ClassB do not overlap. So only one of them may be at the beginning of ClassC. If say ClassA is at the beginning of ClassC, then pA and pC will poit at the same address. The other one will be at some offset from the beginning. Theoretically it could happen that neither is at the beginning.

So the only statement that is always true is C: pA is different from pB.